# Sorting duration and distance using javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

How do I sort distance and duration where lowest duration with the highest distance will be on top.

Example:

```
let obj = [
    {
        duration: 50.1,
        distance: 300,
    },
    {
        duration: 60.9,
        distance: 300,
    },
    {
        duration: 30.08,
        distance: 300,
    },
    {
        duration: 90.0,
        distance: 310,
    },
];
```

Edit:

Here will be the desired results:

If distance is greater than other distance it will be on top even if the duration is highest.

```
let obj = [
      {
         duration: 90.00,
         distance: 310
         
      },
      {
        duration: 30.08,
        distance: 300
      },
      {
        duration: 50.10,
        distance: 300
      },
      {
        duration: 60.90,
        distance: 300
      }
    ]
```

Comment: What if the highest duration has maximum distance? It would be easy to understand if you could add the desired result also. `obj` should be an array instead of an object , if you wanna apply the sorting.

Comment: Is obj valid Object type? Or is obj supposed to be Array type?

Comment: @de highest distance will be on top of lower distance even if it has the largest duration

Comment: It will be array of object, will edit it

Comment: Desired result?

Comment: check my edit at the top @decpk

Answer (score 2):

We can sort array using callback function.

Based on the idea that distance is of higher priority than duraion, we can make a callback function like bellow.

```js
let obj = [
  {
    duration: 50.1,
    distance: 300,
  },
  {
    duration: 60.9,
    distance: 300,
  },
  {
    duration: 30.08,
    distance: 300,
  },
  {
    duration: 90.0,
    distance: 310,
  },
];

obj.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.distance == b.distance) {
    return a.duration - b.duration;
  } else return b.distance - a.distance;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Javascript reference can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Since sort apply the algorithm in-place, You can also do `[...obj].sort(function(a, b) {...`.

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple one-liner

```js
obj.sort((a, b) => b.distance - a.distance || a.duration - b.duration);
```

---

## Example

```js
let obj = [
  {
    duration: 50.1,
    distance: 300,
  },
  {
    duration: 60.9,
    distance: 300,
  },
  {
    duration: 30.08,
    distance: 300,
  },
  {
    duration: 90.0,
    distance: 310,
  },
];

obj.sort((a, b) => b.distance - a.distance || a.duration - b.duration);

console.log(obj);
```